# Python: Select last value of each column that is nonzero in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a command to pick the last element of my matrix that is nonzero. Not the index of the value, but the actual value.
It's a (1001,50001) matrix where the last value of each column isn't the same.

It is not a dataframe, so preferably a numpy command.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example with sample input and expected output. Also, please share your attempt.

Comment: It's a semi long code in a big for loop, but this is what I tried so far, but just returns zeros and not the last nonzero element.
`calving = 2.4
q2[i] = np.min([0, calving * b[i-1] * (h[:,j]!=0).argmin(axis=0)])`

So, the minimum value is just zero, and q2 ends up being a vector of 1000 zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the mask `a!=0`:

```py
a[(a!=0).argsort(axis=0)[-1], range(a.shape[1])]
```

Comment: @JohnGoodWill only remark that if you have a column of just zeros this will fail to detect it. Use some conditional check to do that eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for that. Replace all non-zero values of your column with 1. Then find the last element that is equal to 1. That would be easy even using Unix using grep '1' file | tail -1 , etc. If however you are not allowed to modify the matrix values then you need to just extract this column and run the scripts for this column only. Good luck.